# Blender use as world editor, level editor..etc, License problem?

Tags: modeling, game-engine

Good day,

I just want to ask if I have to disclose my source code?

having condition of:

1. I use my own **MODIFIED** blender as world editor, level editor, game content creation.
2. I am not selling my own modified blender, I am the only one who will use it.
3. I have other game engine that will load the things I made in the blender.

Also, if the answer is YES, can I just make a plugin using python so that I can accomplish the list above and not be required to disclose my source code of my created game and my **modified** blender?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about GPL license conditions. Better ask a lawyer for a profound answer.

Comment: Is there a stackoverflow site which talks about licenses?

Comment: No: *Is there a Stack Exchange site for Law Questions? If not, why not?* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25363/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-law-questions-if-not-why-not

Comment: There's now a [law.stackexchange](http://law.stackexchange.com) and an [opensource.stackexchange](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/) which appear to handle these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't re-distribute the modified Blender, you can do what you like.

You can sell your own modified Blender if you like, as long as you include the source code.